# "560 MILLION pages views per month"

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, grammar

In huge characters in an H1 element near the top of [`https://stackexchange.com/performance`](https://stackexchange.com/performance) is:

> 560 MILLION pages views per month

That should definitely be "pageviews" or "page views". Or maybe "pages viewed".

Comment: Sadly the original bug report has been deleted by SE staff, however it was fixed at some point.